# MongoDB - grantRolesToUser is rolled back?

Tags: mongodb, roles, database

Replicaset - Mongo version 3.2.4, I use bash script to update mongo permission in some situations, something like :

```
mongo <<EOF
  db["grantRolesToUser"]("someone", ["readWriteAnyDatabase"]);
  print(JSON.stringify(db.getUsers()));
EOF
```

Basically, adding readWriteAnyDatabase role to "someone".

It works, and the print shows the user with the new role.
However, 2-3 seconds later. it's gone !!

Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

Comment: Any clues from the logs?

Comment: Issue is MMS/Ops Manager, if you update roles not from the Ops Manager, it will be rolled back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to MMS/OpsManager automatic sync of users across the replicaset.

From the OpsManager Manual:

```
If you want Ops Manager to ensure that all deployments in a group have the same database users, use only the Ops Manager interface to manage users.

If you want certain deployments in a group to possess users not set at the group level, you can add them through direct connection to the MongoDB instances.
```

So you can either control users in the OpsManager or from mongo shell itself, but not both.